# YUI: Adding pjax events to pjax calls

Tags: events, yui

I am using YUI in my project, and using its [pjax](http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/pjax/) utility, I need to add some [Pjax Events](http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/pjax/#pjax-events) to my Pjax calls. I was doing it like:

```
YUI().use('pjax', function (Y) {
        new Y.Pjax({container: '#main_content',
                navigate: function(){
                    alert(1);
                },
                load: function(){
                    alert(2);
                },
                error: function(){
                    alert(3);
                }

        });
    });
```

But the calls are not working for navigate, load or error events, Am i doing somewhere wrong? Any help would be appreciated... Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
var PjaxLoader = new Y.Pjax({container: '#main_content'});  
PjaxLoader.on('load', function(e) {
    Y.log(e.content.node);
});
```